# Python is not connecting to Tor (TorCtl)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to connect to Tor using Python 2.7, but when I try to access a website using urllib or urllib2, it keeps my normal IP. (Im using vidalia)
(Yes it says Tor is running)
Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import TorCtl
password = "" ## your tor password
conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase= password) ## Connect to tor
ip = urllib.urlopen('http://hypersource.net78.net/autos/ip.php').read() ## Get IP address 
print "ip address: " + str(ip)
TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM") ## change IP
ip = urllib.urlopen('http://hypersource.net78.net/autos/ip.php').read() ## Get IP address
print "ip address: " + str(ip)
```

How do I get it to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TorCtl` controls Tor; you still need to configure `urllib` to use a proxy. [Read the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen); you might prefer just setting environment variables over `[, proxies]` for your situation.

Here’s how to use `proxies`, though:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://localhost:9050/'}
ip = urllib.urlopen('http://hypersource.net78.net/autos/ip.php', proxies=proxies).read()
```

If you’re using any other protocol (for example, HTTPS), specify that in `proxies` too.

Comment: @Tyranitar: Oops, sorry. Try `{'http': 'socks://localhost:9050/'}`. Or `socks5://localhost:9050`.

Comment: It still gives me the IP I had before TOR.